# How to package a Quip Live App for AppExchange?

Tags: appexchange, quip, liveapps

I'm working on Quip so as to create a live app that customers of my company can install through AppExchange. I browsed a lot, but couldn't find any resource on how to package a quip live app. Also, I would like to know if there are ways to distribute live apps internally, without listing the app on AppExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have a documented process for publishing to AppExchange, but if you publish a release version of your app, you can request that an admin install it, and everyone at your org will then be able to see it. Additionally, you can add other users as developers if you'd like to test an app without releasing it to your entire org.

Comment: Jesse, could you shed some light on how to distribute the liveapp to customers (people working in other organisations)?

Comment: At the moment this is a manual process done by the Quip team, but in the future we will have a self-serve process for releasing outside your org.